# Why do magento2 cronjobs need to be ran every minute?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, cronjobs

As the title says, I'm really curious if I could set the cronjobs to execute a bit more rare. For example every 10 minutes or so. Is there any specific requirement on why do the magento 2 cronjobs need to be ran every minute?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magento cron process is an internal queue which performs different actions (jobs) at different intervals. To keep these in time in needs to trigger once a minute to maintain the schedule.

Think of a bus being able to run on time and efficiently if it could leave the bus station at any time. However it would be affected (and ones after it) if you chose to only let a bus leave every 10 minutes.

I would only suggest changing the schedule if you are overloading the server you are hosting on. Otherwise keep at at every minute.

Perhaps over simplification but two separate crons as two separate tasks - see here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html#about-the-magento-crontab